# Excel SUMIF with date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are three columns on the excel spreadsheet.

Column A - `Date`
Column B - `ID`
Column E - `amount`

The amount has to be aggregated and I use the following formula, but it does not work -

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E100000; A2:A100000; "=2018.12.21"; B2:B10000; ="132380")
```

Does anyone know what this error is? How to fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO. Kindly share some sample data.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your formula is not consistent, the ranges need to be the same and the equal sign inside the quotes:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E100000; A2:A100000; "=2018.12.21"; B2:B100000; "=132380")
```

This should work if the values in column A (Date) is text. If the values in column A are actually dates, then you can use the `DATE()` function like the below:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E100000; A2:A100000; DATE(2018; 12; 21); B2:B100000; "=132380")
```